# How to make page accessible to logged in users only ? ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I want some strict areas from my site to be forbidden to unknown users . I am using the following code in the subfolder web.config :

```
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
```

and in the web.config of the entire site i have this :

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
 <forms defaultUrl="~/Login.aspx" loginUrl="~/Login.aspx"></forms>
</authentication>
```

if i try to enter the page it doesn't forbid me.
what am i doing wrong ? why this doesn't work ?

Comment: are you sure that you are not logged in? what you are doing should be enough to prevent anonymous users to access your pages

Comment: you can test that by doing <deny users="*"/> and see if it works. If it still allows you to see the page, then you are working with the wrong web.config

Comment: It seems i was already logged in. Thank you.

Comment: Quite rookie mistake. Kinda thought of it. But anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/security/membership/user-based-authorization-cs

Try this it will help you. Also you will find code there

Comment: I kinda solved it. It seems the user was already logged in per session. Thanks anyway.